# How to Deploy and run artifacts in a remote Micro Integrator 4.1.0 instance

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

I have create an API in the Integration Studio ,then i have added a remote server as showing in the screenshoot but it didn't work :

I have added the IP of remote Micro Integrator as server's host name and then adding the server URL with the gateway Port of Micro Integrator which is 8253 .

[image]

[image]

I have followed this documentation :

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/integrate/develop/using-remote-micro-integrator/#deploy-and-run-artifacts-in-a-remote-instance

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, this option only works with Enterprise Integrator. You can try using the [Micro Integrator CLI](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/administer-and-observe/using-the-command-line-interface/) instead to manage Carbon Apps on remote servers.

Comment: The problem is that even i tried with service catalog i cand find my service published in the APIM but it can't be invoked i have used this Config below :

Comment: [server]
hostname = "10.1.1.174" (ip of micro integrator server)
[dashboard_config]
dashboard_url = "https://10.1.1.174:9743/dashboard/api/"
[[service_catalog]]
apim_host = "https://apim.cp.inetumlab.org:9443" (ip of gateway apim)
enable = true
username = "admin"
password = "admin"

Comment: @OussamaNairi This feature and the Service catalog are two different things.